# Reverse proxy Nginx error with accessing munin

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, alias, reverse-proxy

Now,

I have munin setup so that it can be accessed by any virtual domain on my server by adding /munin/ to the end of the virtual domain.
Apache alias setup looks like this ->

```
Alias /munin /home/munin/
```

Now I have just setup nginx as the reverse proxy and everything seems to be working fine with the domain names apart from me being unable to access the munin directory.

If I remove the alias then the munin directory loads up but the static (image files, js files, etc) content doesn't load up.

I have tried adding alias in nginx but that doesn't seem to help by using

```
location /munin {
    Alias /home/munin
}
```

The question is not just bound to this one directory but any other directory for example the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` directory as I am unable to access that aswell after setting up nginx as proxy.

How can I configure nginx to allow me to able to access munin which resides in `/home/munin` by using the format `domainname.com/munin`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
location /munin {
   root /home;
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to this code so that later readers can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a different port for the apache proxy such as 8080 or something then you can access munin directly by using apache by using example.com:8080/munin.

I had the same problem and this was an easy solution